# Create a camera that rotates around the object OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

Im doing the exercises at the end of this tutorial:
[Link](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/)

However Im stuck on the *"Create a camera that rotates around the object"*

```
( position = ObjectCenter + ( radius * cos(time), height, radius * sin(time) ) );
```

I've used the above code supplied to create the following rotation

```
GLfloat radius = 10.0f;
position = glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f) + glm::vec3(radius * cos(glfwGetTime()), 0.0f, radius * sin(glfwGetTime()));
```

Using this the scene rotates around (0,0,0) at a distance of 10, which I thought was the centre of the cube, however it is not, so the cube flashes past the window every so often as the scene rotates.

So how exactly do I find the object centre? I don't understand from the code when I draw the cube where I tell it to centre it to.

For reference the initial position vec is

```
glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3( 0, 0, 5 );
```

Comment: You are doing a global rotation instead of a local rotation. You need to move your camera into local space relative to the player by multiplying the camera by the inverse of the players position. Then apply your rotation.

Comment: or rotate the object in place

Comment: Edit: player's position ==> player's local matrix

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In regards to rotating the object in place I have been trying to translate rotate and translate the model matrix back in the do loop, however it doesn't spin, should I be using some sort of sin function for the angle in the rotate function?

Comment: Ok I got the cube rotating, turns out dividing deltaTime by 1000 was making the angle of rotation so tiny nothing happened! Also realised you wont be able to tell, if you rotating the object or the camera around the object unless you have another item in the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest you can do is to add the following in the **controls.cpp** and declare it in **controls.hpp**

```
glm::vec3 *getPosition(){
    return &position;
}
void setPosition(glm::vec3 var){
    position = var;
}
```

Then you only must declare the following variables in the beginning of the main loop:

```
float rotCamera = 0.0f;
glm::vec3 origPos = *getPosition();
```

and add the following lines just after **glfwPollEvents();** in the main loop:

```
// Swap buffers
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();

//To rotate the camera through the object
if (glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_C ) == GLFW_PRESS){
    rotCamera += 0.01;
    glm::vec3 rot(cos(rotCamera) * 10.0 - origPos.x,  0, sin(rotCamera) * 10.0 - origPos.z);
    setPosition(origPos + rot);
}
```

Finally if you want the camera looking to the cube all time, you must change lookAt from controls.cpp to look always to the (0,0,0):

```
ViewMatrix       = glm::lookAt(position,           // Camera is here
                                glm::vec3( 0, 0, 0 ), //To look always to the cube
                                up                  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                           );
```